# C# Create constructor for a class from outside of the project

Tags: c#, constructor

I have 2 projects, a **DAL** and a **SL**. In my SL project I would like to create a constructor for class **DAL.Student** that takes an object, say **Student(SL.Object object)**. I can create a partial class on my DAL that has this constructor but for a couple of reasons I don't wanna do that since **1.)** I'm using an ORM that generates my DAL classes and **2.)** the object parameter is from the SL and adding a reference to SL from my DAL causes a circular dependency. How do I do this?

Comment: Subclass `DAL.Student` and add a constructor.

Comment: @David Tyron could you possibly tell me on which project should I create the derived class?

Comment: I thought you said you wanted to create it in the SL project?

Comment: I wouldn't mess around with partial or derived classes here. Just create a factory or builder responsible for creating your DAL class from your SL class in your SL assembly.

Comment: Why do you need to specify this `SL.Object` in the constructor? Is it to set some properties when the class is instantiated? If so, a Factory or Builder would be a better solution, like EagleBeak mentions.

Comment: @David Tyron Yes I created the class on my SL project. And well for now subclassing has solved my problem. Jan_V Yes exactly but I will take a look at factory or builder as EagleBeak suggested